# not able to get photo from graph api from SPA front end web app

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, adal.js

I am using ADAL js to authenticate user and i am able to authenticate user successfully. I am able to fetch a token for graph api and read user profile with following url.

```
        GET
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

But i am not able to read user profile picture:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value
```

I get the following error

```
  Object { code: "NoPermissionsInAccessToken", message: "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.", innerError: {…} }
```

I have set the required permissions:

[image]
Is there any way i can check why i am able to fetch profile but not photo.

Content of JWT sent in header before it received 401 error:

```
        {
          "typ": "JWT",
          "nonce": "IenxIPCU1ue14Z9bIIxEidRBBCTnL52w4Q",
          "alg": "RS256",
          "x5t": "huN95IvPf34GzBDZ1GXGirnM",
          "kid": "huN95hq34GzBGXGirnM"
        }
```

Body of JWT token:

```
        {
          "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
          "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/6f1dc6d4-8e90-4593/",
          "iat": 1596560469,
          "nbf": 1596560469,
          "exp": 1596564369,
          "acct": 1,
          "acr": "1",
          "aio": "ATQAy/8QAAAAf64iQ9pAkP+bk/JnXpSNXFPVFqvW/urra8A2QueWm2xaJZM+",
          "altsecid": "5::100320A47F8DD5",
          "amr": [
            "wia"
          ],
          "app_displayname": "graphdemo-dev",
          "appid": "dsfkj32-4350-44a4-dd33-f45b7172b0cd",
          "appidacr": "0",
          "email": "email@domain.com",
          "family_name": "faily",
          "given_name": "given",
          "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/deff24bb-2089-4400378b2/",
          "in_corp": "true",
          "ipaddr": "70.50.13.18",
          "oid": "dskfs77s-5bc6-4fbe-b59a-11fbc2",
          "platf": "3",
          "puid": "A9BDE43D",
          "scp": "profile User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All",
          "sub": "r4-9Ra9nHTjU-g1PvuXwh18",
          "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
          "tid": "d4-8e90-4599-af70-13a4289b3",
          "unique_name": "email@domain.com",
          "uti": "MDGPXbP3lUJMyAA",
          "ver": "1.0",
          "xms_tcdt": 8700342
        }
```

Note: I removed and updated confidential data with random chars.

When i tried on Graph Explorer:

```
        Need admin approval
        Graph explorer (official site)
        microsoft.com
        Graph explorer (official site) needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.
```

```
        import AuthenticationContext from 'adal-angular/lib/adal.js';

        // KPMG
        const config = {
          tenant: process.env.VUE_APP_AZUREAD_TENANTID,
          clientId: process.env.VUE_APP_AZUREAD_CLIENTID,
          cacheLocation: process.env.VUE_APP_CACHE_LOCATION,
          redirectUri: process.env.VUE_APP_REDIRECT_URI
        };


        export default {
          authenticationContext: null,
          /**
           * @return {Promise}
           */
          initialize() {
            this.authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              if (this.authenticationContext.isCallback(window.location.hash) || window.self !== window.top) {
                // redirect to the location specified in the url params.
                this.authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();
              }
              else {
                // try pull the user out of local storage
                const user = this.authenticationContext.getCachedUser();
                if (user) {
                  this.authenticationContext.config.extraQueryParameter = 'login_hint=' + user.userName;
                  resolve();
                }
                else {
                  // no user at all - go sign in..
                  this.signIn();
                }
              }
            });
          },
```

I use below code to get graph api token

```
         acquireGraphApiToken() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              this.authenticationContext.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com', (error, graphApiToken) => {
                if (error || !graphApiToken) {
                  this.signOut();
                  return reject(error);
                } else {
                  return resolve(graphApiToken);
                }
              });
            });
          },
```

Comment: Please share the correlationid and time stamp and have you tried in the graph explorer.

Comment: Sruthi, where do i see the correlation id ? In the token that is sent i dont see anything like that.

Comment: When i tried in graph exploer i get    Need admin approval
   Graph explorer (official site)
   microsoft.com
   Graph explorer (official site) needs permission to access resources in your organization that only an admin can grant. Please ask an admin to grant permission to this app before you can use it.

Comment: Have you   grant admin consent to your application

Comment: No., i ddin't. from the azure portal screenshot i shared in OP, i was assuming it doesn't need, as the "Admin Consent Required" column has no value (-). I thought User,Read by default has it. Please let me know how do i give admin consent. And does it also allow to read all other users photos  with admin consent for any scope?

Comment: Please check  **status** column it must be admin consent with a green tick

Comment: To grant admin consent here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent#grant-admin-consent-in-app-registrations)

Comment: Please update the complete screenshot of Configured permissions

Comment: I just added it and you can see the status  column had admin consent checked.@SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity

Comment: Did the issue fix?

Comment: No. And they were already consented even before i tried i started working on this code.

Comment: Strangely, graph explorer still gives me it needs admin consent.

Comment: yes, you need admin consent for graph explorer because graph explorer separate application and it is not similar to your previous application. Its requires it own permission and also please share inner error details request-id and date

Comment: Ok. Understood. thanks. Here is request id:: {"innerError":{"requestId":"be5b42c6-4ddc-496d-910b-6f3c5c4f6823","date":"2020-08-04T15:23:41","request-id":"be5b42c6-4ddc-496d-910b-6f3c5c4f6823"}}

Comment: Delegated (personal Microsoft account) Not supported for external users

Comment: Soryy i didnt understand your comment. what do i need to do?

Comment: Personal Microsoft account(external user) is not supported v1.0 [photo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions)

Comment: Oh..but i am using my corporate account to sigin and i added some init code in the OP

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft Graph explorer, you need to sign in with an admin account and do the admin consent like this:

[image]

Do the admin consent:

[image]

And from the screenshot above, you can see the access token. After you finish the admin consent, you can decode the access token to see if it includes the required permissions.

For you own Azure AD application, I see that you have done the admin consent based on your screenshot. It's hard to say where the problem is. So my suggestion is to try the [admin consent endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin):

```
// Line breaks are for legibility only.
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/adminconsent?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions
&scope=
https://graph.microsoft.com/calendars.read
https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send
```

Access this url in a browser using an admin account and finish the consent. If the issue still exists, you can create a new Azure AD application and only add the required permission `User.Read` (Don't add other permissions).

Comment: I don't have an admin account. The admin may not give access to graph explorer. So i will ask admin to try the admin consent url.

Comment: I created a new app registration and tried and i get the same error.

Comment: @FullStackBrain Please decode your access token in https://jwt.ms to see what permissions are included. Sharing a screenshot of the permissions is better.

Comment: Hey Thanks. We have asked admin to give the consent. Though the dashboard status is very confusing it doesnt say whether its really granted permission by admin

Comment: @FullStackBrain If the admin has granted consent, the status of the permissions in your Azure AD app will become "Granted for {your tenant}". See this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWglk.png)